# Are these two definitions of the coefficient of determination $R^2$ equal?

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

I want to do multiple linear regression as explained on [this Wikipedia site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Simple_and_multiple_linear_regression): I am given data
$$
yx=(~(y_1,x_{11},\ldots,x_{1p}),\ldots, (y_n,x_{n1},\ldots,x_{np})~)
$$
of $n$-many samples where for each sample $(y_i,x_{i1},\ldots,x_{ip})$ the variable $y_i\in\mathbb{R}$ is ''dependent'' (the ''dependent variable'') from $x_{i1},\ldots,x_{ip} \in\mathbb{R}$. We want to find a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ through these points as one does in (multiple/multivariate) linear regression and as it is explained e.g. [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Formulation).

How good or bad such a hyperplane describes the points of the sample is measured e.g. by the $R^2$-factor or ''coefficient of determination''. This is, as explained [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination), defined as
$$
R^2 = 1-\frac{SS_{res}}{SS_{tot}}
$$
where the values $SS_{res}$ and $SS_{tot}$ depend on the data as explained on the linked Wikipedia-page. (As the notation with the square does not suggest, this may take values in $(-\infty,1]$. If $\bar y=\frac{1}{n}\sum y_i=0$, then this may be equally defined as $R^2=\frac{SS_{reg}}{SS_{tot}}\in[0,1]$.)

**My problem is as follows:** There is [another definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_multiple_correlation#Computation) of $R^2$ - call it temporarily $R_2^2$ - which is given by
$$
R^2_2 = (r_{1y},\ldots, r_{py}) \begin{pmatrix} r_{11}=1 & \cdots & r_{1p}\\
                                                \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
                                               r_p1 & \cdots & r_{pp}=1
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}r_{1y}\\\vdots\\r_{py}\end{pmatrix}
$$
where the $(p\times p)$-matrix in the middle is called the correlation matrix with
$$
r_{ij} = \frac{s_{ij}}{s_{i}s_{j}}\quad\quad\text{and}\quad\quad r_{iy} = \frac{s_{iy}}{s_{i}s_{y}}
$$
the respective correlation coefficients with respective sample variances
$$
s_{ij} = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^n (x_{ki}-\bar{x_{\bullet i}})(x_{kj}-\bar{x_{\bullet j}})\quad\text{and}\quad s_{i} = \sqrt{s_{ii}} \quad\text{and}\quad s_{iy}  = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^n (x_{ki}-\bar{x_{\bullet i}})(y_{k}-\bar{y}) \quad\text{etc.}
$$

**Are these numbers $R^2$ and $R^2_2$ the same and, if yes, why?** Thank you! (I would prefer a linear-algebra-argument without involving probability theory and distributions, etc. - everything is empirical and given here.)

Comment: Cross-post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/631291/119261

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*For Mathematics StackExchange Users convenience, I copied my answer initially posted on Cross Validated to here*:

A good question.  I have to confess that I haven't seen the second expression of $R^2$ before, but here goes the (long) proof:

To clarify, I am assuming you have $p$ regressors (excluding the intercept term), hence in matrix form, the model of your interest (by convention, a linear model contains an intercept $e$ of all ones) is:
\begin{align*}
Y := \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{bmatrix} 
= \begin{bmatrix} e & x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_p \end{bmatrix}\beta + \varepsilon := \begin{bmatrix} e & \tilde{X}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \beta_0 \\ \gamma \end{bmatrix} + \varepsilon, \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align*}
where $x_j = \begin{bmatrix} x_{1j} & \cdots & x_{nj}\end{bmatrix}^\top$, $j = 1, \ldots, p$, $\beta_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ is the coefficient corresponding to $e$, $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}^p$  is the coefficient corresponding to $\tilde{X} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & \cdots & x_p\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$.

The form of your proposed $R_2^2$ inspires me considering the following form of the regression model (known as *Standardized Multiple Regression Model*, see *Applied Linear Statistical Models* by Kutner et al., Section 7.5) -- this is how I managed to bring all the Pearson correlations to the party:
\begin{align*}
Y^* = X^*\beta^* + \varepsilon^*, \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
& Y^* = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{y_1 - \bar{y}}{\sqrt{n - 1}s_Y} \\ \vdots \\ \frac{y_n - \bar{y}}{\sqrt{n - 1}s_Y} \end{bmatrix} = 
(\sqrt{n - 1}s_Y)^{-1}(I - n^{-1}ee^\top)Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}, \tag{3.1}\label{3.1} \\
& X^* = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{x_1 - \bar{x}_1e}{\sqrt{n - 1}s_1} & \cdots & 
\frac{x_p - \bar{x}_pe}{\sqrt{n - 1}s_p} \end{bmatrix} = (I - n^{-1}ee^\top)\tilde{X}(\sqrt{n - 1}\Lambda)^{-1} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}, \tag{3.2}\label{3.2} \\
& \bar{y} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^ny_i, \; s_Y^2 = \frac{1}{n - 1}\sum_{i = 1}^n(y_i - \bar{y})^2, \tag{3.3}\label{3.3} \\
& \bar{x}_j = n^{-1}\sum_{i = 1}^n x_{ij}, \; s_j^2 = \frac{1}{n - 1}\sum_{i = 1}^n(x_{ij} - \bar{x}_j)^2, \; j = 1, \ldots, p, \tag{3.4}\label{3.4} \\
& \Lambda = \operatorname{diag}(s_1, \ldots, s_p) \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}. \tag{3.5}\label{3.5}
\end{align*}
In words, $Y^*$ and $X^*$ are simply standardized versions of original inputs $Y$ and $\tilde{X}$.

With the above notations, on one hand, it is easy to verify that
\begin{align*}
r_{YX} := \begin{bmatrix} r_{Y, x_1} \\ \vdots \\ r_{Y, x_n} \end{bmatrix} = X^{*\top}Y^*, \quad
r_{XX} := \begin{bmatrix} r_{x_i, x_j} \end{bmatrix} = X^{*\top}X^*, \tag{4}\label{4}
\end{align*}
hence
\begin{align*}
\hat{\beta^*} = (X^{*\top}X^*)^{-1}X^{*\top}Y^* = r_{XX}^{-1}r_{YX}. 
\end{align*}

On the other hand, one can express the OLS estimate of $\beta$ in $\eqref{1}$ in terms of the OLS estimate of $\beta^*$ in $\eqref{2}$ as follows (this is easy to verify by substituting transformation definitions $\eqref{3.1}$ -- $\eqref{3.5}$ into $\eqref{2}$ then compare it with $\eqref{1}$, see also the aforementioned reference for derivation details):
\begin{align*}
& \hat{\gamma} = s_Y\Lambda^{-1}\hat{\beta^*} = s_Y\Lambda^{-1}r_{XX}^{-1}r_{YX}, \tag{5.1}\label{5.1} \\
& \hat{\beta}_0 = \bar{Y} - \begin{bmatrix}\bar{x}_1 & \cdots & \bar{x}_p \end{bmatrix}\hat{\gamma} = n^{-1}e^\top Y - n^{-1}e^\top \tilde{X}\hat{\gamma}. \tag{5.2}\label{5.2}
\end{align*}

It then follows by $\eqref{5.1}, \eqref{5.2}, \eqref{3.1}, \eqref{3.2}$ that
\begin{align*}
 & Y - \hat{Y} = Y - e\hat{\beta}_0 - \tilde{X}\hat{\gamma} \\
=& (I - n^{-1}ee^\top)Y - (I - n^{-1}ee^\top)\tilde{X}\hat{\gamma} \\
=& s_Y\sqrt{n - 1}Y^* - s_Y\sqrt{n - 1}X^*r_{XX}^{-1}r_{YX}, 
\end{align*}
whence by $\eqref{4}$ we conclude
\begin{align*}
& (Y - \hat{Y})^\top(Y - \hat{Y}) \\
=& (n - 1)s_Y^2 Y^{*\top}Y^* - 2(n - 1)s_Y^2Y^{*\top}X^{*}r_{XX}^{-1}r_{YX} + (n - 1)s_Y^2r_{YX}^\top r_{XX}^{-1}X^{*\top}X^*r_{XX}^{-1}r_{YX} \\
=& (n - 1)s_Y^2(Y^{*\top}Y^* - r_{YX}^\top r_{XX}^{-1}r_{YX}). \tag{6}\label{6}
\end{align*}
It then follows by $\eqref{6}$ and the definition of $R^2$ that
\begin{align*}
 & R^2 = 1 - \frac{(Y - \hat{Y})^\top(Y - \hat{Y})}{Y^\top (I - n^{-1}ee^\top)Y} \\
=& 1 - \frac{(n - 1)s_Y^2(Y^{*\top}Y^* - r_{YX}^\top r_{XX}^{-1}r_{YX})}{(n - 1)s_Y^2 Y^{*\top}Y^*} \\
=& r_{YX}^\top r_{XX}^{-1}r_{YX}.
\end{align*}
In the last equality, we used the identity $Y^{*\top}Y^* = 1$ (which follows from $\eqref{3.1}$ and $\eqref{3.3}$). This completes the proof.